# Netbeans 7 Git Existing

Tags: git, netbeans

Anyone get Netbeans 7 git plugin working with an existing repo? I am trying to commit to a github repo. (project was based on existing php sources) Is so how? 
Thanks

Comment: The plugin doesnt seem to work with an existing repo....as per the docs and my experimentation. I was looking for a work-around. I am new to git, coming from svn.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to clone your github repo into a local directory.

```
git clone git@github.com:user/Reponame yourlocalfolder
```

Once you do this create a new Netbeans project, using an existing application source, and browse to the folder you just created.  Netbeans should automatically detect the .git repo and the plugin should start working.